# Не подключается сервис Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular2

Есть сервис:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { 
    console.log("Worked");
  }

  getGoals(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/goals")
        .map(res => res.json());
  }


}
```

И есть компонент, куда инжектить сервис:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
import { Goal } from "../goal";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {  
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { 
    this.dataService.getGoals()
        .subscribe(goals => {
            console.log();
        });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Вроде, все сделал правильно, все подключил, но почему-то не конектится.

Comment: сервис надо инжектить в модуль (`module.ts`) или в сам компонент (добавить в @Component  `providers: [DataService ]` ).

Comment: если ошибка `No provider bla bla bla...`, то коммент сверху ответ на твой вопрос

Comment: Vsem spasibo, no problema, byla v tom chto ya ne delal ng build i server tupo ne obnovlyal izmemeneniya.

Comment: Ахахаха - по поводу обновлений - да есть такой косяк и у меня. Поэтому я всегда, прежде чем начну рвать на себе волосы, перезапускаю сервер. В 90% случаев работает))